# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, html, php, mysql

Не отображаются русские буквы. Кодировка на транице и в бд cp1251. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совет : переходите на UTF-8.

HTML должен быть настроен на вашу кодировку :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

MySQL, кодировка соединения должна быть :

```
SET NAMES cp1251
```

Кодировка документа, в котором работает сценарий должна быть **ANSI**(по-моему, тут не уверен)

В файле .htaccess нужно добавить строчку :

```
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
```

Название кодировки вам следует уточнить, т.к. я уже очень давно сижу на **UTF-8**(без BOM).

Answer (score 0):

Может скрипт меняет кодировку на странице?

Comment: нет, щас я чет намудрил, теперь руские буквы не отображаются,кодировки везде cp1251 и на стрнице и в бд.

Answer (score 0):

В каком редакторе кода работаете?
Убедитесь, что сохраняете файл в нужной кодировке.

P.S. Случайно не на **hostinger** выкладываете? 
У меня там тоже были проблемы, пока не перешел на **UTF-8**